# How to include some php class to Joomla tmpls

Tags: php, class, joomla, include, joomla2.5

I need to include some php code that must be repeated in many tmpls. How can I do this, may be as class including? And how can I write php file with my class in a right way? In other words I need something like

**views/category/tpml/default.php**

```
JLoader::register('MyClass', '/administrator/components/com_mycom/helpers/myclass.php');
$repeatedcode = new MyClass();
echo $resultstr;
```

**views/article/tpml/default.php**

```
JLoader::register('MyClass', '/administrator/components/com_mycom/helpers/myclass.php');
$repeatedcode = new MyClass();
echo $resultstr;
```

**myclass.php**

```
class MyClass {
// some code with string for echo in the end
$resultstr = ...
}
```

...

**UPDATE:** @Guilherme thank you! So now it's looking as

The file **/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php:**

```
require_once '/administrator/components/com_mycom/helpers/myclass.php';
MyComHelper::myFunction($param);
$newstring = str_replace($find, $replace, $this->item->text);
echo $newstring;
```

The file **administrator/components/com_mycom/helpers/myclass.php:**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
abstract class MyComHelper
{
    public static function myFunction($param)
    {
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('ua', 'ru')))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__words'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();
    $find = array();
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
     $find[] = $row['ua'];
     $replace[] = $row['ru'];
    }   
    return $find;
    return $replace;
    }
}
```

This script replaces every ua words with matched ru words that are stored in my database and it works if I add the script to tmpl directly. But in the case with including when I open a page with an article I see the blank page which contains only a heading and nothing else i.e. content isn't displayed. Maybe a problem with array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After include the php function in your `Helper`, you can include it on the `tmpl` with the `require_once`

```
    require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/mycom.php';
    MycomHelper::myFunction($param);
```

`MycomHelper` is the class name of my `Helper`

**com_mycom/helpers/helper.php**

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Component Helper
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');

class MycomHelper
{
    public static function dosomething($var)
    {
        return "Helper say: ".$var;
    }
}
```

In my tmpl of a com_content view (first lines)

**components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php**

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');

    if(!defined('DS')) { define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); }
    require_once JPATH_ROOT.DS."components".DS."com_mycom".DS."helpers".DS."helper.php";

    echo MycomHelper::dosomething("hello!!!");
```

And now, you can see the phrase "Helper say: hello!!!" in every article joomla

Comment: oh, the require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/mycom.php'; looks by a Helper in the same component folder. If you need to call one of another folder, change JPATH_COMPONENT by something like "/component/com_mycomponent". But i think that you need to do this on the view

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly this '/administrator/components/com_mycom... but as I wrote I see blank page (however I didn't add any row to any view or controller, but only to tmpl). See update in my post

Comment: I'll can do some tests only tomorrow, maybe I'll find something better than these hints